# mod_wsgi denies permission to write log files inside project folder

Tags: django, deployment, apache2, apache

I am getting the following error while deploying the application using mod_wsgi

```
[Thu Apr 07 11:23:32 2011] [error] [client localhost] IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/vhosts/myproject/myproject.log'
```

Comment: What user is apache running under?  Who owns the `/var/www/vhosts/myproject/` directory?

Comment: I have created a custom user and assigned it in httpd file

Comment: This is valuable for cycling of Django logs and placement the directory is only part of the solution, I think.  I set up a log using 

            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/tmp/logs/django/mydjangolog.log',

But the initial permissions are set to rw-r, meaning no one but the owner and group can even read the log.  

But some reason, on the 2nd cycle, the group (which was apache) changes.  By 3rd log file, httpd can no longer read the  log file to cycle, and the server locks up.
How do you determine file permissions of the log file?

Answer (score 7):

It is a bad idea to put the log folder within the project folder. The process that apache uses should never have write permissions to your project folder. Put it in a `/tmp/`  folder or the like.

Comment: This is not complete a directory issue.  Even if you put it in /tmp/  the httpd user might not be able to cycle a log file.   Starting from a directory called /var/tmp which is drwxrwxrwx we create a logs/django directory which are also drwxrwxrwx.

Answer (score 3):

Read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Access_Rights_Of_Apache_User

for information about access rights of user that application will run under when using Apache/mod_wsgi.